# How can I invoke linux programs from C#/Mono?

Tags: c#, mono, nant, monodevelop

I've been using MonoDevelop and Make to execute some build taks on a C project under linux, but I decided to abandon Make and switch to NAnt since I am more proficient in writing C# programs than Make/shell scripts, so I decided to write a custom NAnt task in C# to replace my Makefile. So, how can I invoke GCC or other shell commands from C#?

I also need to know how to block the execution until GCC returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the same as on Windows - use System.Diagnostics.Process. Beware that if you redirect stdout/stderr and the buffers fill up (which is entirely possible using GCC) it can deadlock, so harvest those into StringBuilders.

```
var psi = new Process.StartInfo ("gcc", "-gcc -arguments") {
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
};
var error  = new System.Text.StringBuilder ();
var output = new System.Text.StringBuilder ();

var p = Process.Start (psi);
p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
p.OutputDataReceived +=
    (object s, DataReceivedEventArgs e) => output.Append (e.Data);
p.ErrorDataReceived  +=
    (object s, DataReceivedEventArgs e) => output.Append (e.Data);

p.WaitForExit ();
```

FWIW, you might like to consider using custom tasks for MSBuild (i.e. Mono's "xbuild") instead of NAnt, because MonoDevelop's project files are MSBuild files, and MonoDevelop has xbuild integration.

Comment: Great code man, I didn't knew MsBuild allowed custom tasks and will certainly look into that.

Comment: MonoDevelop has C project types so it must already have a task for executing gcc right? If so, how can I access that task progamatically on my own custom task? And more importantly, how can I 'insert' my own custom task into a MonoDevelop Project?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

http://mono-project.com/Howto_PipeOutput

It's essentially the same as .NET on Windows.